# HTML: stop Child elements from inheriting parent's [title] attribute

Tags: html, inheritance, title

The issue is that when I declare a title attribute for a 'wrapper' element, the a tool-tip shows up when the cursor falls inside the 'content' element as well. How do I prevent this(inheritance) from happening?

```
<style> 
  #content{ margin:25px;}
</style>

<div id='wrapper' title='example'>
  <div id='content'>

  </div>
</div>
```

(I only want the tool-tip to show up *between* the edges of the 'content' and 'wrapper' elements, instead of in both)

Comment: According to this source [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.title) you have to set inner DIV title as well, to a white character. Anyway - you have to do that for Firefox. Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work well in IE.

Comment: @mj82 unfortunately that leads to blank tooltip appearing in IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with pure CSS or HTML.

One way to hack this is using client side code.. basic plain JavaScript example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    oDiv.onmouseover = function() {
        this.parentNode.setAttribute("old_title", this.parentNode.title);
        this.parentNode.title = "";
    };
    oDiv.onmouseout = function() {
        this.parentNode.title = this.parentNode.getAttribute("old_title");
    };    
};
```

This will "clear" the parent `div` title upon mouse over of the contents, and restore the title when the mouse leave the contents.

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/UASPZ/

Comment: Great idea, but I had to scratch the whole implementation as it mouse over was triggering more frequently than expected, due to other elements inside of #content. (I could use e.stopPropagation(); for each, I suppose. Anyways, I will think about it)

Comment: @whamsicore sorry I couldn't help more.. if you need any further help with this feel free to ask. :)

Comment: mouseenter and mouseexit may be better.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I found out that you can prevent this by giving the child elements a dummy title `title=" "`.

Comment: At least this works in firefox 4 ;) I just found out, that chrome doesn't like it. And Opera ignores it completely =(

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here.

Found out that specifying `title=' '` works for Chrome and FireFox but shows annoying tool-tip with one space in IE. `title=''` works for IE but completely ignored by Chrome and FireFox thus showing parent's tool-tip.

Didn't figured out how to make in cross-browser :(

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible, as explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)

> Title attribute inheritance
>
> If an element has no title attribute, then it inherits it from its
> parent node, which in turn may inherit it from its parent, and so on.
>
> If this attribute is set to the empty string, it means its ancestors'
> titles are irrelevant and shouldn't be used in the tooltip for this
> element.

This creates the following solution for your problem:

```
<div id='wrapper' title='example'>
  <div id='content' title=''>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have confirmed that this works in Firefox and Chrome.