# Revert bound title attribute to parent title

Tags: html, angular, typescript, property-binding

This is the opposite of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881954/html-stop-child-elements-from-inheriting-parents-title-attribute).

I have a child element in a parent element (in this case a `matSelect` in a `matCard`, which is probably irrelevant) with a `title` set for the parent element. The child element may or may not supply its own `title`:

```
<mat-card title="Parent title">
  <mat-select [title]=getChildTitle()>
  </mat-select>
</mat-card>
```

Is there anything I can return from `getChildTitle()` to get it to revert to the parent's `title` text, or is the only way I can do this to specify the Parent title again, à la `[title]=getChildTitle() ?? 'Parent title'`? Just returning `undefined` doesn't seem to do it - then my title text reads "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You provide a little context on how these titles are passed in. I will assume that you have a component that will use `mat-card` and `mat-select`.

In the my-component.ts

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-component',
      templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
      styleUrls: ['my-component.css'],
    })
    export class MyComponent{
      
       @Input()
       public parentTitle: string;

       @Input()
       public childTitle?: string;

       public function getChildTitle() {
          return this.childTitle ?? this.parentTitle;
       }
    }
```

In the my-component.html

```
<mat-card [title]="parentTitle">
  <mat-select [title]=getChildTitle()>
  </mat-select>
</mat-card>
```

In the app-component.html

```
<!-- this will use parent for both parent and child title -->
<my-component parentTitle="Parent"></my-component>
```